# How to open one form inside another form without in pop-up

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a masterPage form and I want that a client page form should get open inside it, not in another window. So that, I could have only none master page for the application in C#.

Comment: Do you mean that you want an MDI window?

Comment: Could you expand further on what do you need? I believe I've understood you but I need more information to be sure what you are asking about in order to provide an answer that might be able to help you

Comment: [MDI Parent Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-parent-forms)

Comment: Hard to visualize a "none master page".  But surely you'd want to take advantage of inheritance in Winforms.  Design a form with the plumbing that needs to be common, then use Project > Add New Item > Inherited Form to take advantage of it.  Embedding a UserControl in a form is also a very common technique.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `MDI` form.

Set IsMdiContainer as true of your master page

For opening child form use below code**

```
childPage objForm = new childPage();  
objForm.MDIParent = this;    
objForm.Show();
```